# How to custom color selected cell?

Tags: ios, swift2, uitableview

When a tableview cell is selected, the default gray color appears. I'd like to change this to something more transparent. Is there a way to do this to `.selectionStyle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`selectedBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectedBackgroundView). Make a UIView, give it transparent `backgroundColor`, and set it.